# Wildcard for string before @ character

Tags: sql, wildcard

How would I use a wildcard to filter out any permutation of the following. There can be any number of zeros before the "@" character.
Example

```
   0@test.com
   000000@test.com
   00000000000@test.com
```

Basically, I'm looking to wildcard any email address with only zeros before the @ character.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you !

Smiddy

Comment: have you tried WHERE col LIKE '*@test.com'

Comment: Add some different sample data, and also specify the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: @Sergey, Wouldn't it be LIKE '%@test.com'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL:

To remove all values with only zeros before the @

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM (SELECT  '000@test.com' AS[values]  ) [table]
WHERE
    LEN(REPLACE((LEFT([values],CHARINDEX('@',[Values])-1)),'0',''))  <> 0
```

*-- LEFT & CHARINDEX    : get the result LEFT of the @

-- LEN & REPLACE        : After all 0 are replaced by '' any email that contained only zeros will result in len = 0.*

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just looking to remove any email address that has only zeros before the @ character.

Comment: I edited the proposed answer with the code to remove all email addresses with only zeoes

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with a regular expression, but the concrete answer depends on your database vendor and the available syntax.

- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE email ~ '^0+@'
  ```
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE email REGEXP '^0+@'
  ```

  Synonyms are `email RLIKE '^0+@'` and `REGEXP_LIKE(email, '^0+@')`.
- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(email, '^0+@')
  ```